# cannot convert the system.uri to system.type

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I Am creating a new universal windows app in the visual studio 2015. In the main page i am using frame to navigate one page to another page. but i cannot assign the page to navigate.It shows like this error **cannot convert the System.uri to System.Type**. I don't know why the same code working in the wpf properly but i can't in UWP. What is the reason for this??

```
       mainframe.Navigate(new System.Uri("firstpagedemo.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

This is my code how can i change the type of that parameter. 
Mainframe is my frame's name.

Comment: You need a typeof operator. Look carefully at the samples

Comment: could you please help me to solve this @kennyzx???

Comment: something like mainframe.Navigate(typeof(firstpagedemo)). You get this error becuase the method accepts a Type, not a Uri. find MSDN for reference.

Comment: that works @ken

Answer (score 2):

In UWP, the [`Frame.Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702396.aspx) method takes the type of the Page as argument:

```
mainframe.Navigate(typeof(firstpagedemo));
```

Comment: Correct, or if you want to use string based navigation, use [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism).